# Conditional calculating the numbers of values in column with R, part2

Tags: r, aggregate, apply

I have three vectors:

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,3,3,  3,3,3,4,4,  5,5,5,5,5 )
y <- c(2,2,1,3,2, 1,4,2,2,NA, 3,3,3,4,NA, 1,4,4,2,NA)
w <- c(1,45,NA,45,NA,45,41,45,96,25,12,NA,7,NA,4,45,12,45,32,56)
```

How can I find the number of values in W (don`t count NA) for each X (from 1 to 5) and for each Y (from 1 to 4)?

The output should be in format like:

```
y x  result
4 1   ...
4 2   ...
4 3
4 4
4 5
3 1
3 2
3 3
3 4
3 5
...
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4 
1 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use xtabs to sum up the values where `w` is not NA

```
 dd<-as.data.frame(xtabs(!is.na(w)~y+x), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

the `as.data.frame` part changes it form a table to a long format as you desire. The only catch is that `xtabs` converts `x` and `y` to characters. You can convert them back to numeric with

```
dd$x <- as.numeric(dd$x)
dd$y <- as.numeric(dd$y)
```

and then sort with

```
dd <- dd[order(-dd$y,dd$x),]
```

Comment: Thanks. Very simple solution. But how to show in results y from 4 to 1 but not from 1 to 4?

Comment: The result is a data.frame. You may sort it however you like.

Comment: Hi, could you please tell me one more thing. We have the same three columns x,y and w. And we need to find the number of values in W (don`t count NA) for each Y (from 1 to 4) but  x split in groups: if x<=2 group I, if 2<x<=5 group II. So consider X not like 1,2,3,4,5 but like two groups I and II. Thank you.

Comment: @user3542209 instead of `y+x` you could use `y+I(x<2)` in the aggregate(). Or you could create a new variable with the proper groups and use that instead of `x`.

Comment: Could you please take a look at that question I posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687475/conditional-calculating-the-numbers-of-values-in-column-with-r-part3

Comment: Is it possible provide with examples, don`t understood you a little )

Comment: Hi MrFlick, could you answer the question please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,3,3,  3,3,3,4,4,  5,5,5,5,5 ),
  y = c(2,2,1,3,2, 1,4,2,2,NA, 3,3,3,4,NA, 1,4,4,2,NA),
  w = c(1,45,NA,45,NA,45,41,45,96,25,12,NA,7,NA,4,45,12,45,32,56)
) 

dat %>%
  filter(!is.na(w)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(y)) %>%
  group_by(y,x) %>%
  summarise(result = n())

   y x result
1  1 2      1
2  1 5      1
3  2 1      2
4  2 2      1
5  2 3      1
6  2 5      1
7  3 1      1
8  3 3      2
9  4 2      1
10 4 5      2
```

The above simply gives the number of non-NA values of `w` for all non-NA levels of `x` and `y`
If you want to see *all* combinations of non-NA levels of `x` and `y`, you can make them first by using `expand.grid`

```
foo <- dat %>%
  filter(!is.na(w)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(y)) %>%
  group_by(y,x) %>%
  summarise(result = sum(!is.na(w)))

with(dat, expand.grid(x = unique(x),
                      y = unique(y))) %>%
  filter(!is.na(y)) %>%
  left_join(foo) %>%
  arrange(desc(y))

   x y result
1  1 4     NA
2  2 4      1
3  3 4     NA
4  4 4     NA
5  5 4      2
6  1 3      1
7  2 3     NA
8  3 3      2
9  4 3     NA
10 5 3     NA
11 1 2      2
12 2 2      1
13 3 2      1
14 4 2     NA
15 5 2      1
16 1 1     NA
17 2 1      1
18 3 1     NA
19 4 1     NA
20 5 1      1
```

This technique gives you NA for "results" wherever the factor combination of x and y doesn't exist

Comment: Thank you! But how to show rows in results with NA. You have 10 rows but how to make all 20 rows? And to make it with y from 4 to 1 but nit from 1 to 4.

Comment: Edited!  the short answer is: create all the rows you want with `expand.grid`, and reorder your result with `arrange`

Comment: Hi. DO you know how to make the same calculations by groups x and y, but split x by subgroups:   if 0 < x <= 2 group I, 
  if 2 < x <= 3 group II and 
  if 3 < x <= 5 group III.  Thank you!