# Conditional calculating the numbers of values in column with R

Tags: r, aggregation

I have two vectors:

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,3,3,  3,3,3,4,4,  5,5,5,5,5 )
y <- c(2,2,1,3,2, 1,4,2,2,NA, 3,3,3,4,NA, 1,4,4,2,NA)
```

This question ([Conditional calculating the numbers of values in column with R, part2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331593/conditional-calculating-the-numbers-of-values-in-column-with-r-part2)) discussed how to find the number of values in `w` (don't count `NA`) for each `x` (from 1–5) and for each `y` (from 1–4).

Let's split `X` by groups: if `x<=2`, group `I`; if `2<x<=3`, group `II`; and if `3<X<=5`, group `III`. I need to find the number of different values in `x` by groups and by every value of `y`. I also need to find the mean of those values in `x` by the same groups. The output should be in this format:

```
y x    Result 1 (the number of distinct numbers in X); Result 2 (the mean)
1 I     ...
1 II    ...
1 III   ...     
...
4 I     ...
4 II    ...
4 III   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

My command of R code isn't great, so here's A Rather Ugly Function:

```
ARUF=function(x,y){df1=data.frame(x,y,group=NA);miny=min(y,na.rm=T)
maxy=max(y,na.rm=T);for(i in 1:length(df1$x))df1$group[i]=if(df1$x[i]<=2)'I'else
if(df1$x[i]>2&df1$x[i]<=3)'II'else if(df1$x[i]>3&df1$x[i]<=5)'III'else'NA'
Result1=c();Result2=c();for(i in miny:maxy){for(j in c('I','II','III')){
Result1=append(Result1,length(levels(factor(subset(df1,y==i&group==j)$x))))
Result2=append(Result2,mean(subset(df1,y==i&group==j)$x))}}
print(data.frame(y=rep(miny:maxy,rep(3,maxy+abs(miny-1))),
x=rep(c('I','II','III'),maxy+abs(miny-1)),Result1,Result2),row.names=F)}
```

With your `x` and `y`, `ARUF(x,y)` prints this `data.frame`:

```
y   x Result1  Result2
1   I       2 1.500000
1  II       0      NaN
1 III       1 5.000000
2   I       2 1.250000
2  II       1 3.000000
2 III       1 5.000000
3   I       1 1.000000
3  II       1 3.000000
3 III       0      NaN
4   I       1 2.000000
4  II       0      NaN
4 III       2 4.666667
```

I went a little out of my way to make `ARUF` robust with any integer values of `y`. I can't seem to break it by generating `y` randomly with `rbinom`, and I believe it should handle any real number values of `x`, so it should work for any other vectors of the same kind that you might have.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Bring in data.table library
require(data.table)
data <- data.table(x,y)

#Summarize data
data[, list(x = mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)), by = 
       list(y, x.grp = cut(x, c(-Inf,2,3,5,Inf)))][order(y,x.grp)]
```

---

If you'd like the results to be `NA` when `NA`s are present, then just remove `na.rm=TRUE` from `mean(.)`:

```
data[, list(x = mean(x)), by = 
       list(y, x.grp = cut(x, c(-Inf,2,3,5,Inf)))][order(y,x.grp)]
```