# Conditional calculating the numbers of values in column with R part 2

Tags: r, list, aggregate, data.table

I have two vectors:

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,3,3,  3,3,3,4,4,  5,5,5,5,5 )
y <- c(2,2,1,3,2, 1,4,2,2,NA, 3,3,3,4,NA, 1,4,4,2,NA)
```

Here ([Conditional calculating the numbers of values in column with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697468/conditional-calculating-the-numbers-of-values-in-column-with-r)) was discussed the question how to find the mean of values in x by Y and X , when X is spited by groups:

```
  if x<=2, group I
  if 2<x<=3, group II
  if 3<X<=5, group III
```

The best solution was offered by @Mike.Gahan :

```
#Bring in data.table library
require(data.table)
data <- data.table(x,y)

#Summarize data
data[,list(x=mean(x,na.rm=T)),by=list(y,x.grp=cut(x,c(-Inf,2,3,5,Inf)))]  [order(y,x.grp)]
```

But this solution doesn`t put rows with NA in result.

Does anybody know how to output all rows in result including rows with NA ?

Now the output is :

```
         y    x.grp    x
     1:  1 (-Inf,2] 1.500000
     2:  1    (3,5] 5.000000
     3:  2 (-Inf,2] 1.250000
     4:  2    (2,3] 3.000000
     5:  2    (3,5] 5.000000
     6:  3 (-Inf,2] 1.000000
     7:  3    (2,3] 3.000000
     8:  4 (-Inf,2] 2.000000
     9:  4    (3,5] 4.666667
    10: NA    (2,3] 3.000000
    11: NA    (3,5] 4.500000
```

Where X is the mean of numbers in X by each group and by Y

Comment: it's unclear what you want the output to be..?

Comment: Ok, yes, that's the output - what is it that you don't like about it? The question is unclear at this point - what do you *want* the output to be?

Comment: @eddi for example for y=1 and x=(2,3] there is result NA, but in current output this row is missed as soon as others rows with NA. Please , let me know if you have more questions )

Comment: you should add those after your grouping operation, e.g. assuming each interval occurs at least once in your final result: `setkey(result, y, x.grp); result[CJ(unique(y), unique(x.grp))]`

Comment: @eddi Great, it works, thank you! But it also shows NA in Y in results but I need to have only 1,2,3,4 for Y in results )

Comment: well, you have NA's to begin with in your `y`, so either remove those NA's before you do the grouping, or after - up to you which way you go

Comment: @eddi Ok, I am trying to do that, but I know how to replace NA with smth but don`t know how to delete them.

Comment: @eddi I did that! Thank you.

Comment: @user3827724, I guess the Q is answered? If so, it's best if you could please answer the question yourself and mark as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
setkey(result, y, x.grp)
result[CJ(unique(y), unique(x.grp))]
```

Thanks to @eddi !